# Trying to select all fields in a row with the lowest MIN( )

Tags: mysql, min

I'm having trouble trying to select the lowest price and the unique url that's in the same row, at the moment it's getting the unique_url from the first row.

```
SELECT 
  MIN( price ), `unique_url` 
FROM `product_price` 
WHERE `barcode` = '" . $product_barcode . "' 
  AND `active`  = '1' 
GROUP BY `user_id` 
ORDER BY `price` ASC 
LIMIT 1
```

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT MIN( price ) as mPrice, `unique_url` 
FROM `product_price` 
WHERE `barcode` = '" . $product_barcode . "' AND `active` = '1'
GROUP BY `user_id` 
ORDER BY mPrice ASC 
LIMIT 1
```